# Convergence of a particular integral over $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

My professor left this as exercise:

> Verify that $$\int_\mathbb {R^n}\frac 1 {\vert x\vert^\alpha}dx\lt\infty$$ if and only if $\alpha\lt n$.

However, I can't see how this is true, since with $n=1$ we have $\int_\mathbb R \frac 1 {\vert x\vert^\alpha}dx$ that is never finite; with $n=2$ we have $\int_{\mathbb R^2} \frac 1 {\vert \bf x \vert^\alpha}dx=\int_{\mathbb R^2} \frac 1 {(x^2+y^2)^{\frac \alpha 2 }}dx$, that should be finite for $\alpha =1$, for example. However if we change to polar coordinates it's clear that the integral is not finite.

Can you tell me where I'm wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its possible your prof said to integrate on a bounded set, like the unit ball around 0. This one is convergent for that range of alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is not true. Let $a<n$

$$\int_{\Bbb{R}}\frac{1}{|x|^a}dx \geq  \int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x|^a}dx=+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Using  polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^{n}$ you can see that this integral is not finite for any value of $\alpha$!